# How to Sort a ListView Faster?

Tags: c#, listview, sorting

I have found a solution in MSDN for ListView sorting...
But I found the code to be taking too much time to display the ListView properly when a column is clicked...
So I am asking for a solution to speed it up.  I have to sort a ListView containing more than 10,000 items.  Here is my whole code...

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ListViewSorter
{
    class ListViewSorter
    {
        const Int32 HDF_SORTDOWN = 0x200;
        const Int32 HDF_SORTUP = 0x400;
        const Int32 HDI_FORMAT = 0x4;
        const Int32 HDM_GETITEM = 0x120b;
        const Int32 HDM_SETITEM = 0x120c;
        const Int32 LVM_GETHEADER = 0x101f;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessageLVCOLUMN(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, ref LVCOLUMN lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LVCOLUMN
        {
            public Int32 mask;
            public Int32 cx;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
            public string pszText;
            public IntPtr hbm;
            public Int32 cchTextMax;
            public Int32 fmt;
            public Int32 iSubItem;
            public Int32 iImage;
            public Int32 iOrder;
        }
        public void SetSortIcon( ListView listview, int ColumnIndex)
        {
            IntPtr clmHdr = SendMessage(listview.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            SortOrder sorting = listview.Sorting;
            for (int i = 0; i < listview.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                IntPtr clmPtr = new IntPtr(i);
                LVCOLUMN lvColumn = new LVCOLUMN();

                lvColumn.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
                SendMessageLVCOLUMN(clmHdr, HDM_GETITEM, clmPtr, ref lvColumn);
                if (sorting != SortOrder.None && i == ColumnIndex)
                {
                    if (sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                    {
                        lvColumn.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTDOWN;
                        lvColumn.fmt |= HDF_SORTUP;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lvColumn.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTUP;
                        lvColumn.fmt |= HDF_SORTDOWN;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lvColumn.fmt &= ~HDF_SORTDOWN & ~HDF_SORTUP;
                }
                SendMessageLVCOLUMN(clmHdr, HDM_SETITEM, clmPtr, ref lvColumn);
            }
        }
        public int SortColumn(ListView listview, int ColumnIndex, int sortColumn)
        {
            if (ColumnIndex != sortColumn)
            {
                sortColumn = ColumnIndex;
                listview.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                if (listview.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                    listview.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
                else
                    listview.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }
            SetSortIcon(listview, sortColumn);
            listview.Sort();
            listview.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(ColumnIndex,
                                                              listview.Sorting);
            return sortColumn;
        }
    }
    class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
    {
        private int col;
        private SortOrder order;
        public ListViewItemComparer()
        {
            col = 0;
            order = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        public ListViewItemComparer(int column, SortOrder order)
        {
            col = column;
            this.order = order;
        }
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            int returnVal;
            try
            {
                System.DateTime firstDate =
                        DateTime.Parse(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text);
                System.DateTime secondDate =
                        DateTime.Parse(((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
                returnVal = DateTime.Compare(firstDate, secondDate);
            }
            catch
            {
                returnVal = String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text,
                            ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
            }
            if (order == SortOrder.Descending)
                returnVal *= -1;
            return returnVal;
        }

    }
}
```

---

Can anyone help me out of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways that comes in my mind now is use od `data-binding` and set `VirtualMode` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx. Property to `true`.

Doing so you wil achieve foliwing:

- your big custom data `data-layer` custom management. In other words you make a sort on **data** and bind it to `listview` and not sorting `listview` items.
- `listView.VirtualMode=true;` will force `listview` control **to create listview items only for that items  that are visible in ui**. In other words, if you have 10.000 items in `datacollection` but on UI I can se only 15 of them, due the window dimension, the **rendering and lustviewitem ui artifact** creation time will be spend only for 15 and not for 10.000 like it does in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still need a bit hint how to use data-binding with virtual mode...Actually I dont understand about the data-binding..

Comment: @writz: This can be helpfull http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListView_DataBinding.aspx

Comment: I found a [BindableListView Control](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/utilities/bindablelistview/)...Will it be fine??..[I am actually figuring out the code there]

Comment: @writz: just by lokking on source provided, seems a stuff you need. May be even slightly more complicated then you need, but it's hard to say for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try defining the datatypes instead of using object. Forcing the complier to figure out the dt's takes extra time.